# Ubuntu 10.x playing ALL DVD videos: via a simple GUI app, precise instructions required for every day folk, please

Tags: ubuntu, video, dvd, playback, film

Is there a DVD player *application* i.e. a graphical user interface for Ubuntu that plays ALL DVD Videos, encrypted, non-encrypted, home made DVDs, "CSS" DVDs?

Is it easy and straight forward to install and guaranteed to work?

(Obviously looked at VLC Player (won't play a commercial DVD I've got - does nothing, no error message), Movie Player (error message something like can't open/can't play). I've also looked at Xine, libCSS, MPlayer and the indication of how success they might work for all DVDs in their documentation seems vague, or the Synaptic package manager doesn't download everything, or there is a command line instruction which works for older versions of Ubuntu and/or it reports something missing, directory not found, or possibly assumes you've done something else beforehand.)

Comment: if VLC won't play it, I don't know what will! :)

Comment: @studiohack - VLC DOES play it BUT in Windows 7. I'm using the exact same PC/DVD drive - the PC is dual boot: Boot into Windows 7 and it plays on VLC *perfectly*. Boot into Ubuntu and it DOESN'T play on VLC - latest version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to answer my question - the answer at the moment appears to be: NO - there isn't a guaranteed method to play all DVD-Videos in Ubuntu.

The City of God Region 2 DVD-Video of the film I have won't play, frozen screen, covered in green macroblocks, in Ubuntu.

***BUT on the exact same PC and drive booted into Windows 7, it plays perfectly on VLC.***

Credit to @dev for their answer - their answer is the official answer it seems for Ubuntu - as they reference. However this answer *only* applies to some DVD-Videos as it *does* work for some other films I have bur not the one above. On that basis, the answer cannot be the accepted answer, the I have upvoted @devs answer.

I've opened a thread on the Official Ubuntu forums to specifically track my issue:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=10179508

Comment: Also added post to official VLC videolan.org forum here: http://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=84903

Answer (score 5):

Have you installed libdvdcss2?
This page should help you out: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/PlayingDVDs

Just to Clarify, you just need to use these two commands:

```
sudo apt-get install libdvdread4
```

and then:

```
sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
```

After this, I usually use VLC to play the DVD, since IMHO, it's the best Media player out there.

Comment: I assume that you are on 10.04. Is that your version?

Comment: Yes, I have 10.04 but would also like to try 10.10. Thanks so much for answering, I will get back to you tomorrow evening when I can get to my Ubuntu machine.

Comment: Sorry I am unlucky - the steps don't work for me, even after a reboot. I am trying to play "City Of God" DVD-Video, Region 2 on my 1.8Ghz Core Duo Intel 2Gb RAM Ubuntu 10.04 desktop with ATI HD4350 Radion graphics. Can you suggest anything else I can do?

Comment: the problem I get is a frozen screen in VLC player (version 1.0.6 "Goldeneye") with green "macroblocks" with some of the picture.

Comment: I'm probably going to create my own answer in the next day or so to say that the solution is not 100% guaranteed i.e. to say that my original question is not possible on all Ubuntu machines. By the way, the same machine booted into windows plays the DVD without problems.

Comment: DVDs having been around for 15 years, one would think that today's Ubuntu versions should be able to play DVDs - a common format without problem. Although it is a proprietary format, so is MP3, AAC and MP4 - and these play fine, also much of the hardware that Ubuntu such as the CPU (Intel) is proprietary, so an argument against supporting proprietary products in open source systems doesn't hold and would be overly dogmatic in my view. My thoughts aren't aimed at anyone here. I'm greatful for your attempts to help, @dev

Comment: +1 upvote as it does work for some other DVDs but not the one I mention. The one I mention above plays perfectly on the same PC and drive booted into windows running vlc.